# how can I traverse all devices attached to system and get their struct device in a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, kernel-module, device-driver

I want to write a function in my custom **kernel module**, which can perform 'traverse through **all** devices attached to system and get their `struct device*`', in order to unregister all device drivers using `driver_unregister(struct device_driver *drv)` with `device_driver*` field of `struct device` as argument.

Expecting to find something like `list_head head_of_all_devices` as a global variable (so I can use things such as `list_for_each_entry` to access every device), I had took a look at `struct device_node *of_node` inside of `struct device`, ended up sadly as it is only used in ARM architecture not in x86.

**To summarize, is there any data structure or kernel API function that allows kernel module programmer to traverse through all device's `struct device*` in a simple manner?**

Comment: There is no such thing in the Linux kernel.

Comment: That's sad :( thanks for comment though

Comment: You may try to go over each bus available in the kernel, but it may not cover 100% of the devices registered in the kernel.